# Encode Int to Bytes using logical operators

Tags: javascript, logic, byte, integer-arithmetic

I've been doing some work on **logical arithmetic** recently. I want to encode unsigned integers (Uint's) and signed integers (Int's) as bytes.

Below is a code snippet that currently translates UInts to bytes and vice versa. Unfortunately I got some problems while encoding **signed integers** with my tactic.

Encoding for Integers will be performed using this shift and mask method for both - unsigned and signed integers.

```
for (let i=0; i<n; i++)
    buffer.push((value >>> (i*8)) & 0xFF);
```

---

So what is wrong with my `readInt`-method and how to fix this?

```js
const buffer = [];

const writeIntN = (value, n) => {
  for (let i=0; i<n; i++)
    buffer.push((value >>> (i*8)) & 0xFF);
}
const readUint = (n, offset) => {
  let v=0;
  for (let i=0; i<n; i++)
    v |= (buffer[offset++] << (i*8));
  return v >>> 0;
}
const readInt = (n, offset) => {
  return readUint(n, offset) << (8*n) >> (8*n); // error is here
}


const writeUInt16 = (value) => writeIntN(value, 2);
const readUInt16 = (offset) => readUint(2, offset);


const writeInt16 = (value) => writeIntN(value, 2);
const readInt16 = (offset) => readInt(2, offset);

const writeInt8 = (value) => writeIntN(value, 1);
const readInt8 = (offset) => readInt(1, offset);



writeUInt16(20);
writeInt16(-20);
writeInt8(-42);
console.log(buffer);
console.log(readUInt16(0));
console.log(readInt16(2));
console.log(readInt8(4)); // how?
```

---

**Note**: I know about the basic operations to decode 8,16-bit signed ints but how to get this inside the for loop in `readUint` more efficient?

Decoding 8-bit signed integers: `(buffer[offset++] << 24) >> 24`

Decoding 16-bit signed integers: `(((buffer[offset++] << 0) | (buffer[offset++] << 8)) << 16) >> 16`